# I am trying to install MongoDB and I get this error "Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating"

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to install MongoDB, but I having some difficulties  I get this

```
C:\Users\HP>mongod
2016-05-09T19:48:32.489-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4
284 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=hp_pc
2016-05-09T19:48:32.490-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/W
indows Server 2008 R2
2016-05-09T19:48:32.490-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.6
2016-05-09T19:48:32.490-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 05552b562c7
a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25
2016-05-09T19:48:32.490-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL
 1.0.1p-fips 9 Jul 2015
2016-05-09T19:48:32.490-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-05-09T19:48:32.490-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-05-09T19:48:32.491-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-05-09T19:48:32.491-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ss
l
2016-05-09T19:48:32.491-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-05-09T19:48:32.491-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-05-09T19:48:32.491-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-05-09T19:48:32.492-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndList
en: 29 Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2016-05-09T19:48:32.493-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
C:\Users\HP>
```

So, I decide to create the db folder within the DB folder and I input this into the command line

```
`mongod --dbpath C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\data\db`
```

However, I get an error

```
Invalid command: Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\data\db
```

I have created the file. I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Did you set mongodb environment variable? If you didn't do it, you have to run mongod from >C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a space in your command

```
`mongod --dbpath C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\data\db`
```

It should be

```
mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\data\db"
```

Answer (score 0):

'test' folder is automatically created while installing mongodb. Can you see 'test' folder? If yes then, use below:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongod.exe --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data
```

Answer (score 0):

you must create db folder from root .
eg md \data\db instead of md data\db.

Answer (score 0):

This anwser is:

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin>mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data"
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:32.899+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:32.902+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.717+07:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.718+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.722+07:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.722+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.723+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.723+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.726+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1424,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/data","architecture":"64-bit","host":"LAPTOP-HBS5B8J5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.726+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.727+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.9","gitVersion":"6f7dae919422dcd7f4892c10ff20cdc721ad00e6","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.728+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19044)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.728+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"storage":{"dbPath":"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.738+07:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.739+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.744+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.744+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.744+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.745+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.746+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.746+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.747+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.747+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.751+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.752+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.752+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.753+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.754+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.754+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.755+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.756+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.756+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-02T17:20:33.757+07:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).